# Can I setup a link SQL server connection between servers on different networks?

Tags: sql-server, database, hosting

We have a production SQL server hosted offsite at a hosting company, and we have a staging environment within our own network.  We want to be able to setup a SQL job that copies content from a table on the staging server to prod on a regular basis, and I think we need to setup a linked server connection to do this.  What do I need to get the hosting company to do to allow us to set this up?  We have RDP access to the production servers, I just need to know what network and security configurations need to happen from the hosting company's perspective so I can ask them to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linked server is not the best option.

- it opens the SQL Server for remote T-SQL execution, a very serious security hole
- it requires SQL password based authentication because of the different domains involved
- it does not offer any redundancy when faced with spotty conectivity
- TDS as a protocol is not designed for speed

A much better alternative is to use [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166043(SQL.90).aspx):

- SSB operates on a dedicated port that does not allow arbitrary T-SQL commands, like a linked server
- SSB supports certificate based authentication accross distinct domains
- Message fragmentation and delivery fairness ensures a smooth operation over bad/slow connections
- SSB uses a high throughput protocol designed for speed, sam eprotocol used in database mirroring.

If you insist on the linked server then you must:

- enable SQL Server to listen on the public internet addressed
- enable TCP ion the server and open the SQL listenening port (default TCP 1433) on the firewall. If the server listen on non-default ports, the you must start the SQL Browser service and open port 1434 UDP on the firewall, and allow sqlservr.exe to open arbitrary ports on the firewall.
- you must enable SQL Authentication to allow for SQL based password.
- To protect the traffic you should ensure SSL is used see [How to enable SSL encryption for an instance of SQL Server by using Microsoft Management Console](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;316898) and [How to Enable Channel Encryption](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/04/476705.aspx).
- Check, re-check and double-recheck that the [sa] login has a bulletproof password that is known only by people that you have absolute 100% trust. Your TDS port opened to the internet will be subject to a constant barage of brute force attacks on [sa] from a million automated bots.