# Secure communication between linked SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server-2005, encryption

Is the data transferred between two linked SQL Servers protected (encrypted) by default? If not, is there a way to accomplish this?

I have two SQL Server 2005 databases running on separate servers, separate machines, separate networks. How can I ensure that data transmitted from one linked server to another is secure? I have tried researching the subject but am unable to find anything.

Many thanks, 
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I was pointed in the right direction by this posting:

[Can I setup a link SQL server connection between servers on different networks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/98084/can-i-setup-a-link-sql-server-connection-between-servers-on-different-networks)